# Throw compile error if @Nullable / @NonNull parameters are used incorrectly

Tags: java, android, gradle, nullable, non-nullable

I'm using com.android.support:support-annotations library to add @Nullable and @NonNull annotations to my project.

After I switched Editor->Inspections "Constant conditions & exceptions" and "@NonNull/@Nullable problems" inspections to "Error" level in Android Studio, I was able to see incorrect usages of @Nullable and @NonNull parameters in my code:

```
private void testNullable(@Nullable String value) {
    if (value != null) {
        // this line works fine
        testNonNull(value);
    }

    // this line is highlighted as an error in Android Studio
    testNonNull(value);
}

private void testNonNull(@NonNull String value) {
    testNullable(value);
}
```

Unfortunately, even though IDE marks one of the lines as an error, the project compiles without build errors (I'm using standard way of building android project with gradle).

Is there a way to make gradle throw compilation error in the code listed above?

Comment: The eclipse compiler can be configured to raise warnings or errors from null annotations. It can be used in ant and maven builds, and surely also from gradle. I just haven't seen the corresponding configuration for gradle. Maybe these hints help: https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/FAQ#Can_I_use_JDT_outside_Eclipse_to_compile_Java_code.3F